# Ошибка при записи данных в List

Tags: c#, unity3d

Реализовал таблицу рекордов, реализовал запись в неё. При тестировании в Unity проблем нет, при создании билда и запуске на android или PC запись рекорда в таблицу не происходит, ни принудительно через код, ни после смерти персонажа и вызова функции. Пробовал преобразование типов, но ничего не изменилось. Выдаётся ошибка с PID 29116 и [0x00023] in <391300e255ec4a5db95b581d02f33539>:0 ошибкой какого-либо номера.

```
public void SendRecord() {
    int score = Convert.ToInt32(Collect.score);
    string text = Convert.ToString(inputField2.text);
    Debug.Log(Equals(score) + "" + score);
    // highScoreTable.AddHightScoreEntry(564654, text);
    // highScoreTable.AddHightScoreEntry(564654, "test");
    // highScoreTable.AddHightScoreEntry(score, "test");
    highScoreTable.AddHightScoreEntry(score, text); // вызываем функцию для создания элемента List
}

// скрипт collect.score
public static int score;
public Text TextScore;
void Start() {
    TextScore = GetComponent<Text>();
}
void Update() {
    TextScore.text = "Счёт: " + score;
}

// скрипт highScoreTable
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class highScoreTable : MonoBehaviour {
    private Transform entryContainer;
    private Transform entryTemplate;
    private List<HightScoreEntry> hightScoreEntryList;
    private List<Transform> hightScoreEntryTransformList;

    public void Awake() {
        entryContainer = transform.Find("highScoreEntryContainer");
        entryTemplate = entryContainer.Find("highScoreEntryTemplate");

        entryTemplate.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        
        string jsonString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("hightScoreTable");
        HightScore hightscore =  JsonUtility.FromJson<HightScore>(jsonString);

        if(hightscore.hightScoreEntryList.Count == 0) { 
        //проверочное условие, которое при отсутствии элементов записывает в массив хоть какой-нибудь элемент
            hightScoreEntryList = new List<HightScoreEntry>() {new HightScoreEntry{ score = 35435, name = "asdasd"}, };
            hightScoreEntryTransformList = new List<Transform>();
            foreach (HightScoreEntry hightScoreEntry in hightScoreEntryList) {
                createHightScoreEntryTransform(hightScoreEntry, entryContainer, hightScoreEntryTransformList);
            }
            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(hightScoreEntryList); 
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("hightScoreTable", json);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("hightScoreTable"));
        } 

        for(int i = 0; i < hightscore.hightScoreEntryList.Count; i++) { // сортируем массив
            for(int j = i + 1; j < hightscore.hightScoreEntryList.Count; j++) {
                if(hightscore.hightScoreEntryList[j].score > hightscore.hightScoreEntryList[i].score) {
                    HightScoreEntry tmp = hightscore.hightScoreEntryList[i];
                    hightscore.hightScoreEntryList[i] = hightscore.hightScoreEntryList[j];
                    hightscore.hightScoreEntryList[j] = tmp;

                    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(hightscore); // перезаписываем отсортированный массив
                    PlayerPrefs.SetString("hightScoreTable", json);
                    PlayerPrefs.Save();
                }
            }
        }
        int n=10;
        int k = hightscore.hightScoreEntryList.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < (hightscore.hightScoreEntryList.Count - n); i ++ ) { // цикл для удаления лишних элементов и сохранения результата
            if(hightscore.hightScoreEntryList.Count > n) { 
                hightscore.hightScoreEntryList.RemoveAt(k-1);
                string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(hightscore);
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("hightScoreTable", json);
                PlayerPrefs.Save();
                Debug.Log(hightscore.hightScoreEntryList.Count);
                Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("hightScoreTable"));
            }
        }

        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("hightScoreTable"));
        hightScoreEntryTransformList = new List<Transform>();
        foreach (HightScoreEntry hightScoreEntry in hightscore.hightScoreEntryList) { // цикл для создания UI элементов 
            createHightScoreEntryTransform(hightScoreEntry, entryContainer, hightScoreEntryTransformList);
        }
    }
    // метод для создания элементов в таблице рекордов
    public void createHightScoreEntryTransform(HightScoreEntry hightScoreEntry, Transform container, List<Transform> transformList) {
        float templateHight = 45f;
        Transform entryTransform = Instantiate(entryTemplate, container);
        RectTransform entryRectTransform = entryTransform.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        entryRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, -templateHight * transformList.Count);
        entryTransform.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        int rank = transformList.Count +1;
        string rankString;
        switch(rank) {
            default:
                rankString = rank + ""; break;
            case 1: 
                rankString = rank + "ый"; break;
            case 2: 
                rankString = rank + "ой"; break;
            case 3: 
                rankString = rank + "ий"; break;
        }
        entryTransform.Find("position (1)").GetComponent<Text>().text = rankString;

        int score = hightScoreEntry.score;
        entryTransform.Find("score (1)").GetComponent<Text>().text = score.ToString();
        
        string name = hightScoreEntry.name;
        entryTransform.Find("name (1)").GetComponent<Text>().text = name;

        transformList.Add(entryTransform);
    }
    // метод для добавления новых результатов в таблицу
    public static void AddHightScoreEntry(int score, string name) {
        HightScoreEntry hightScoreEntry = new HightScoreEntry { score = score, name = name};

        string jsonString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("hightScoreTable");
        HightScore hightscore =  JsonUtility.FromJson<HightScore>(jsonString);
        
        hightscore.hightScoreEntryList.Add(hightScoreEntry);
        
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(hightscore);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("hightScoreTable", json);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    public class HightScore {
        public List<HightScoreEntry> hightScoreEntryList;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class HightScoreEntry {
        public int score;
        public string name;
    }
}
```

[image: При нажатии на кнопку записи результата выдаётся подобная ошибка]

Comment: Вообще на android `AddHightScoreEntry` не происходит, даже если туда просто передавать данные типа (3423, "sds"). Может с ключами что-то не так, раз значения хранятся локально?

Comment: Не пишите дополнительную информацию в комментарии, вместо этого вы можете отредактировать сам пост. А комментарий удалите.